# Comment rating plugin for wordpress.

Tags: rating

i want to know, which is this comment rating plugin ?

used here http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/08/10/showcase-of-delicious-coffee-websites/

plz have a look at comment section

Answer (score 1):

it seems like a custom or a modified plugin at the very most its named **smash-commentratings** on the site you mentioned and the closest plugin to that one is this one named [comment rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-rating/) but if you want to use a rating plugin i will advice [gd star ratting](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/) which offers not only the comment thumb rating but many more type that can also be used in posts.

Comment: i found, it's wp-postviews